# Webpack bundle.js not executing

Tags: webpack

I'm using webpack to run my web application.
Today, my bundle.js stopped working abruptly and I'm trying to figure out why.

Here's my `webpack.config.js`:

```html
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|html)$/, // Use a regex pattern to match both .js and .html files
        enforce: "pre",
        use: ['source-map-loader', 'html-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  ignoreWarnings: [/Failed to parse source map/],
  watch: true,
};
```

Here's my hierarchy:

```html
-public
  -dist
    -bundle.js
  -src
    -index.js
index.html
```

Here's my `index.html`:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <script src="./dist/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `index.js`:

```html
console.log('You won't see this');
```

Even a simple console.log won't execute..
What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: It just "stopped working"? No errors? Console errors? Errors during running webpack?

Comment: I meant that it just isn't executing at all. I found a solution though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

I changed my `webpack.config.js` module to:

```html
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.html$/, // This pattern will only apply the loaders to .html files
        use: ['html-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // This pattern will only apply the loaders to .js files
        enforce: "pre",
        use: ['source-map-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
```